# How to decorate a method that belongs to another class in my current class?

Tags: python, decorator

We have an internal library that returns a kafka consumer object. What I want to do is implement a decorator which uses this object to start the consumer (the method to start the consumer also comes from that internal library). The aim is to import this decorator and use it for any method which needs the consumer to be started before execution. Here's a snippet from a file say, utils.py:

```
from internal_library import KafkaMsgConsumer
class KafkaMessageConsumer(object):

    def __init__(self, topic_name, kafka_host, kafka_port='some_port'):
        self.topic_name = topic_name
        self.kafka_host = kafka_host
        self.kafka_port = kafka_port
        self.consumer = KafkaMsgConsumer(kafka_host_name=(str(self.kafka_host) + ":" + str(self.kafka_port)),
                         topic_name=self.topic_name)

    def consumer_required(self):
        def decorator():
            consumer = self.consumer.start_consumer()
            return consumer
        return decorator
```

Then there's my main script where I want to use this decorator. Contents from script.py:

```
mes = KafkaMessageConsumer(topic_name='some_topic', kafka_host='some_host',
                           kafka_port='some_port')


@mes.consumer_required()
def post_act():
    ''' some processing goes here before which I require the consumer to be started'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools


def consumer_required(self):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self.consumer.start_consumer()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

Your decorator needs to accept the decorated function as an argument and you need to return a corresponding wrapper:

```
from functools import wraps

def consumer_required(self):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self.consumer.start_consumer()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Alternatively you can also inject the `consumer` into the decorated function via

```
kwargs.update(consumer=self.consumer.start_consumer())
```